# What happens if no threads are waiting and condition signal was sent?

Tags: c++, pthreads

What happens if all threads are busy and main thread has sent thread cond signal ?

1 Main Thread and 3 pthreads in thread pool. 3 pthreads are in status of

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sync_mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&sync_cond, &sync_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sync_mutex);
```

Main thread has sent Signal to wake up the threads to process the work. In this situation, What if 3 threads are already busy and next signal has arrived?

Comment: If no one is waiting for a signal, the signal will have no effect. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I was wondering if it waits until a thread gets available

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing. The signal disappears.

Comment: Thank you, then to avoid this do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to record the times/count of signals even if there is nothing waiting yet, use a semaphore.  Semaphores have a count, condvars events etc. do not.

Comment: Semaphores.. I'll check on it thanks. what about using a simple queue to store the events and dequeue from it when Thread gets available?

Comment: @Jae: a condition variable **signals a change in condition**.  The receiving threads must wait for a condition variable until a condition is met, which  when using queues means wait until the queue is not empty (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5538447/104774).

Answer (score 4):

If your using one of the following functions:

`pthread_cond_signal` - restarts one of the threads that are waiting on the condition variable cond.
`pthread_cond_broadcast` - wake up all threads blocked by the specified condition variable.

The manual states that

> The  pthread_cond_broadcast() and pthread_cond_signal() functions
>   shall have no effect if there are no threads currently blocked on
>   cond.