# Producer-Consumer: Lost Wake-up issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, boost-thread

I was trying to write code for Producer-Consumer problem. Below code works fine most of the time but stuck sometimes because of "Lost Wake-up" (i guess). I tried thread sleep() but it didn't work. What modification is needed to handle this case in my code? Is semaphore can be helpful here ? If yes, how will i implement them here ?

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int product = 0;
boost::mutex mutex;
boost::condition_variable cv;
boost::condition_variable pv;
bool done = false;

void consumer(){
    while(done==false){
        //cout << "start c" << endl
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock);
        //cout << "wakeup c" << endl;
        if (done==false)
        {
            cout << product << endl;
            //cout << "notify c" << endl;
            pv.notify_one();
        }
        //cout << "end c" << endl;
    }
}

void producer(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        //cout << "start p" << endl;
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(50000));
        ++product;
        //cout << "notify p" << endl;
        cv.notify_one();
        pv.wait(lock);
        //cout << "wakeup p" << endl;
    }
    //cout << "end p" << endl;
    cv.notify_one();
    done = true;
}

int main()
{
    int t = 1000;
    while(t--){
        /*
        This is not perfect, and is prone to a subtle issue called the lost wakeup (for example, producer calls notify() 
        on the condition, but client hasn't really called wait() yet, then both will wait() indefinitely.) 
        */
        boost::thread consumerThread(&consumer);    
        boost::thread producerThread(&producer);

        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();
        done =false;
        //cout << "process end" << endl;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check my answer on how to deal with condition variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5538447/104774, they should not be used as signals, but just to notify that a condition has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want a way to know (in the consumer) that you "missed" a signal. A semaphore can help. There's more than one way to skin a cat, so here's my simple take on it (using just c++11 standard library features):

```
class semaphore
{
private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int count;

public: 
    semaphore(int count_ = 0) : count(count_) { }

    void notify()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        ++count;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void wait() { return wait([]{}); }  // no-op action

    template <typename F>
    auto wait(F&& func = []{}) -> decltype(std::declval<F>()())
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

        while(count == 0){
            cv.wait(lck);
        }
        count--;

        return func();
    }
};
```

For convenience, I added a convenience `wait()` overload that takes a function to be executed under the lock. This makes it possible for the consumer to operate the 'semaphore' without ever manually operating the lock (and still get the value of `product` without data-races):

```
semaphore sem;

void consumer() {
    do {
        bool stop = false;
        int received_product = sem.wait([&stop] { stop = done; return product; });

        if (stop)
            break;

        std::cout << received_product << std::endl;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(processed_mutex);
        processed_signal.notify_one();
    } while(true);
}
```

A fully working demo: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c7fd9c6bfb0ffd3)**:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

class semaphore
{
private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int count;

public: 
    semaphore(int count_ = 0) : count(count_) { }

    void notify()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        ++count;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void wait() { return wait([]{}); }  // no-op action

    template <typename F>
    auto wait(F&& func = []{}) -> decltype(std::declval<F>()())
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

        while(count == 0){
            cv.wait(lck);
        }
        count--;

        return func();
    }
};

semaphore sem;

int product = 0;
std::mutex processed_mutex;
std::condition_variable processed_signal;

bool done = false;

void consumer(int check) {
    do {
        bool stop = false;
        int received_product = sem.wait([&stop] { stop = done; return product; });

        if (stop)
            break;

        std::cout << received_product << std::endl;
        assert(++check == received_product);

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(processed_mutex);
        processed_signal.notify_one();
    } while(true);
}

void producer() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(processed_mutex);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ++product;
        sem.notify();
        processed_signal.wait(lock);
    }
    done = true;
    sem.notify();
}

int main() {
    int t = 1000;
    while(t--) {
        std::thread consumerThread(&consumer, product);
        std::thread producerThread(&producer);
        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();
        done = false;
        std::cout << "process end" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: the processed_signal notification can still get lost

Comment: @stefaanv I'd appreciate if you demonstrated how. I think the `processed_mutex` amply protects that. The consumer can't possibly signal the `processed_signal` (a slight misnomer, btw :)) until it gets the mutex: hence, by definition the producer is waiting on the condition variable first.

Comment: you're right, although this mainly works because of the lock around the complete producer thread which in most cases beats the purpose of having threads, but here it is okay.  I didn't spot that.

Comment: @stefaanv Actually, that lock is _logically_ not a lock here. It's a synchronization primitive. Think of it as a "negative critical-section"; it is 'opened up' while waiting for the condition variable. Sure it could be tuned, but that's for the OP to decide

Answer (score -1):

You seems to ignore that the variable `done` is also a shared state, to the same extend as `product`. Which can lead to several races conditions. In your case, I see at least one scenario where `consumerThread` make no progress:

1. The loop execute has intended
2. consumer executes, and is waiting at `cv.wait(lock);`
3. producer has finished the for loop, and notify consumer and is preempted
4. consumer wakes up, read `"done==false"`, output product, read `done == false` again, wait on the condition
5. producer set done to true and exit
6. consumer is stuck forever

To avoid these kind of issues you should be holding a lock when reading or writing done. Btw your implementation is quite sequential, ie the producer and the consumer can only process a single piece of data at the time...

Comment: even if you move all reads/write to `done` inside the critical section (trivial: [just move the `scoped_lock`s outside the loop](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b330b0ee81c3e6ea)) the dead lock still can happen