# pthread_cond_timedwait not returning after specified timeout

Tags: pthreads

In the following code `execute_on_thread()` will keep on printing ".",
while the `main` function waits for a condition to be signaled from `execute_on_thread` using `pthread_cond_timedwait`. However, it is not timing out after the specified 20 second timeout, it just keeps printing ".", nothing else is happening.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHOW_TECH_CMD_MAX_EXEC_TIME       5 //in secs 
pthread_mutex_t waitMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t waitCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *execute_on_thread();
void *execute_on_thread()
{
  pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_lock( &waitMutex );
  while(1)
  {
    printf(".");
  }
  pthread_cond_signal( &waitCond );
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &waitMutex );
  return (void *) 0;

}
int main( )
{
  pthread_t tid;
  struct timespec   ts;
  int error;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
  ts.tv_sec += 20; 
  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,execute_on_thread,NULL);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&waitMutex);
  error = pthread_cond_timedwait(&waitCond, &waitMutex,&ts);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&waitMutex);
  printf("come here 1\n");
  if(error == ETIMEDOUT)
  {
    printf("come here 2\n");
    error = pthread_cancel(tid);
    if(error != 0)
    {
       printf("come here 3\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait):

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be
>   owned by the calling thread.

So, before `pthread_cond_wait` returns, be it due to a signal arriving or timing out, it tries to lock the mutex. But - since `execute_on_thread` never releases the mutex once it has it (due to the `while(1)` loop), `pthread_cond_wait` will be stuck waiting on the mutex to be unlocked.

If you for instance change your `execute_on_thread` to temporarily unlock the mutex during each cycle, you should be able to get it to work. For instance:

```
void *execute_on_thread()
{
  pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);   //Not necessary - this is the default state for new threads
  pthread_mutex_lock( &waitMutex );
  while(1)
  {
    printf(".\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&waitMutex);
    usleep(100*1000);                 //So that the screen doesn't completely fill up with '.'s
    pthread_mutex_lock( &waitMutex );
  }
  pthread_cond_signal( &waitCond );
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &waitMutex );
  return (void *) 0;
}
```

Note though, that there are a couple of other things that could be improved in your program - such as adding a guard variable to your conditional wait (have a look at [condition variable - why calling pthread_cond_signal() before calling pthread_cond_wait() is a logical error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536759/condition-variable-why-calling-pthread-cond-signal-before-calling-pthread-co)), adding a cleanup handler to make sure the mutex is unlocked if the cancel request is handled by `execute_on_thread` when the mutex is locked and similar tweaks.